# Sending data with POST method from Arduino to PHP

Tags: php, sockets, post, arduino, wifi

I'm trying to send some data to the server. When I use this code alone, works properly. But when I add my other program code to Arduino; variable `postRequest` doesn't get a correct value(as shown in the figure).

**correct result**
[image]
and when add my other program code the result:
**incorrect data**
[image]

arduino code:

function for send data:

```
boolean httpPOST(String data, String server, int port, String uri, String* response) {
    // initiate TCP connection
    String tcpStart = "AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\"" + server + "\"," + port;
    Serial.println(tcpStart);
    // prepare the data to be posted
    String postRequest =
        "POST " + uri + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
        "Host: " + server + ":" + port + "\r\n" +
        "Accept: *" + "/" + "*\r\n" +
        "Content-Length: " + data.length() + "\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" 
        "\r\n" +
        "record=123456789876543212345678765";

    // notify ESP8266 about the lenght of TCP packet
    String sendCmd = "AT+CIPSEND=0," + postRequest.length();

    esp8266.println(tcpStart);
    if (esp8266.find("OK")) {
        Serial.println("TCP connection OK");
         Serial.println(postRequest);
        Serial.println(postRequest.length());
        jj=1;

        esp8266.print("AT+CIPSEND=0,");
        esp8266.println(postRequest.length());
        delay(500);
        if (esp8266.find(">")) {

            Serial.println("Sending packet...");

            esp8266.println(postRequest);
            if (esp8266.find("SEND OK")) {
                Serial.println("Packet sent");
                while (esp8266.available()) {
                    String tmpResp = esp8266.readString();
                    response = &tmpResp;
                }
                // close the connection
                esp8266.println("AT+CIPCLOSE=0");
                Serial.println("close");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                Serial.println("An error occured while sending packet");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            Serial.println("ESP8266 is not listening for incoming data");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("Cannot initiate TCP connection");
        return false;
    }
}
```

that function called in loop:

```
void loop(){
//some codes ..

if (check()) { //check function for checking connected esp8266 Module to arduino
        resetESP8266();
        if (connectWifi("apwifi", "password")) {
            delay(5000);
            String response="";
            boolean ok = httpPOST("record="+record, "192.168.1.109", 80, "/lab/include/reciv.php", &response);
            if (ok) {
                Serial.println(response);
            }
            else {
                Serial.println("Something went wrong while posting data");
            }
        }
       }
//some codes..
}
```

Comment: This means your postRequest.length() is 0. You are not getting output from the device. Can you give more details of the connected devices to arduino and any sketch of your project?

Comment: yes it's NULL. In addition to the WiFi module esp8266, clock module (ds3231) and NRF rc522 is connected to the Arduino. The other codes to operate them. For example, the library <wire.h> (This library allows you to communicate with I2C / TWI devices) when the library is added to the program, its value is not variable. @AmitRay

Comment: it is interesting!! When we reduce the amount of data sent (String postRequest =
        "POST " + uri + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
        "Host: " + server + ":" + port + "\r\n" +
        "Accept: *" + "/" + "*\r\n" +

        "record=123456789876543212345678765";
), postRequest amount is variable and is sent correctly.

Comment: How are you powering your ESP ? If it's from the Arduino, it's normal to have this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Program doesn't working properly only when other codes are added . have encounter same problem your self? what is the solution? @Ouss4

Comment: I asked you how are you powering your ESP. If it is from the Arduino, try to power it from an external supply that can deliver more power (and have a commun ground with the Arduino).

Comment: I also use an external power supply, But it still was not working properly! - @Ouss4